# How to stream video from Raspberry Pi camera module as http not RTSP?

Tags: camera, opencv, streaming-video

How to stream video from Raspberry Pi camera module as http not `rtsp`? I use this command to stream as `rtsp` but i need http because of OpenCV. `raspivid -o - -t 0 -rot 180 -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 30 -b 2000000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream}' :demux=h264`

Comment: [V4L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux) has a very simple interface that will provide a hardware accelerated (html 5 based?) http stream with the Pi camera.  You'll have to search around a bit for details -- I can't recall off them off the top of my head but hopefully someone will be by with either a link/dupe question or an answer.   Depending on the purpose you may want to separate the stream from the html wrapper and put it in your own page, which is also pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -rot 180 -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 30 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8010}' :demux=h264
```

Then, on your client go to:

```
http://<IP-OF-THE-RPI>:8010
```